# While loop exit condition

Tags: while-loop, exit

I want to know how this while loop exits? Because i and j are not incremented anywhere except at s.charAt(j++) and s.charAt(i++) which is to find char at j or ith position. Does that also increment j and i? In my opinion it should only give you the character code at j++ or i++ th position isn't it so?

```
public class Solution {
    public int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
        int n = s.length();
        Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
        int ans = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
        while (i < n && j < n) {
            // try to extend the range [i, j]
        if (!set.contains(s.charAt(j))){
            set.add(s.charAt(j++));
            ans = Math.max(ans, j - i);
        }
        else {
            set.remove(s.charAt(i++));
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

}

Comment: `i++` will change the value stored in `i`.

Comment: thank you! that's what i believed it would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes using i++ increments the value of i.
If you want to find character at next position than i, then you can simply use another variable and store i+1 value in it and use that to access character. Like this:

```
z = i+1;
set.add(s.charAt(z));
```

using post-increment or pre-increment always changes the value of increment variable and only differ as to when they increment the increment variable's value.

Comment: Thank you! Now i seem to have got it.

Comment: If the answer helped you, please accept it. Cheers :)